# How do I change the row that numbers are compared based on the data in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am usually good with conditional formatting in excel/google sheets, but here is my current challenge.  I am needing to format specific cells based on the data in a table at the top of the sheet where the row used for comparison changes based on the value in one cell. Here is the link to the sheet I am currently working on.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t7pgvGjxs1Eb3cCcRnLDA6E9ov5riEDAjn-fX3A0s8I/edit?usp=sharing

-The table at the top of the is the reference table and does not change.
-the number in column E is the data that determines which row of the table to compare the data in columns G through AN

The Situation:
Let's look at Name 3.
The numbers in G18:AN18 are compared to the G12:AN12 because of the matching number in E18 and E12
If the number in G18 equals G12 - no formatting change
If the number in G18 is one less than G12 - fill color Yellow
If the number in G18 is more than one less than G12 - fill color Red
This is true for each cell in row 18 columns G:AN
 - That's the easy part -
Now, when the number in E18 changes (from "9" to "10" for example), I need it to stop looking at row 12 and now look at row 13 because E18 now matches E13

I know that I can do it using nested IF/AND statements but I would have to do it for each and every cell individually.  How can I do this more easily through google sheets?

Comment: This is not an Excel question. Please remove the tag

Comment: VLOOKUP might do the work for you: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318

Comment: thanks dMd, but VLOOKUP returns a value and I don't need any values returned.  I need conditional formatting to occur based on the number in Column E and then change which row it checks against when the value in Column E changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use INDEX/MATCH, so for the yellow formatting starting in G16:-

```
=G16=INDEX($G$4:$R$14,MATCH($E16,$E$4:$E$14,0),COLUMN(A:A))-1
```

The idea is that as you copy it across the column changes to B:B etc. so you get the next column of the top region and as you copy it down you get whichever row matches E16, E17 etc.

I'm sure you can modify it for the red formatting and also to take account of any blank cells.

Also, in this particular case that the numbers in E4:E14 are just the numbers 1-11, you could use E16:E25 to index directly into G4:R14 and make the formula a lot simpler like this:-

```
=G16=INDEX($G$4:$R$14,$E16,COLUMN(A:A))-1
```

Comment: Thank you Tom.  That was perfect.  The numbers were just numbers so I was able to use just the index.  I never thought about using the COLUMN formula there.